# Linux sort adds new line at the beginning of the file

Tags: linux, sorting

I have a text file which contains a word list which I want to sort. For example:

```
z
x
c
w
f
g
a
b
```

I run `sort file.txt` and everything is fine. Words get sorted.
But sometimes I get a new line at the beginning of the sort output like this:

```
>>>>new line here<<<<
a
b
c
....
```

I've noticed that when the list is short, I don't get a new line. When it's longer, the new line gets added.
I don't understand why that happens and how to prevent that?

Comment: Next time when you see `>>>>new line here<<<<`, try `grep "new line here" file.txt`